# Using Fubini's Theorem to find an infinite sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to find the sum

$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)x^n$$

using Fubini's Theorem. Essentially, I need to figure out how to write my original summation as a double sum instead. I know how to use Fubini's once I have the double sum, but my problem is I do not know what sum to use. I assume I need to rewrite all or part of $\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}$ as a sum. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)x^n
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \right)\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}x^n\\\tag{1}
&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=i}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{1}{2-x}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{2^i}\\
&=\frac{2}{(2-x)^2}
\end{align*}

where the interchanging of summation in (1) is justified by noting that the series converges absolutely for $|x|<2$ by using the root test for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)x^n.$$  By root test, we know that the radius of convergence is $2$, so $f$ is defined on $(-2,2)$.  Its primitive function $$F(x) = C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}})=\frac{1}{1-x/2}+C=\frac{2}{2-x}+C$$ for all $x \in (-2,2)$.  Differentiate it once gives $$f(x) = F'(x) = \frac{2}{(2-x)^2}.$$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

A general identity that will help you in this case is $\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)f(n)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge k}f(n)$.